# openssl cms -verify doesn't work with external certificate

Tags: openssl, cryptography, signing, smime

I've been investigating this for a couple of days, and I finally came up with a simple test case. I need to sign and verify the signature for a SMIME/CMS formatted file which MUST NOT include the certificate.

Signing works fine, but verification only works if the certificate is embedded in the signed file AND openssl is allowed to use it. If I don't include the certificate OR if I tell openssl to ignore it, verification fails, even if I specify both the signer certificate and the CA certificate explicitly in both scenarios.

I have the following files:

- `ca-crt.pem` – the CA certificate
- `server-crt.pem` – the certificate I'm using for signing
- `server-key.pem` – the server's private key
- `sample.xml` – a sample file I want to sign

**Step 1: Generate the signed file:**

```
$ openssl cms -sign -signer server-crt.pem -inkey server-key.pem -nodetach -md sha256 -in sample.xml -outform der -out sample.cms-der -noattr
```

Notice I didn't ask openssl to exclude the certificate. In the final version I would have to also add `-nocerts`, but for now it's easier to test if we leave it in.

**Step 2: Verify the signature using the embedded certificate**

Ok, so now we have the signed file in `sample.cms-der` – let's first verify it using the certificate included in the signed file:

```
$ openssl cms -verify -CAfile ca-crt.pem -inform der -signer server-crt.pem -in sample.cms-der
Verification successful
```

**Step 3 Alpha: Verify the signature ignoring the embedded certificate**

Now let's ask openssl to ignore the certificate embedded in the signed file – I'm using the exact same command line, except I'm adding the `-nointern` option at the end:

```
$ openssl cms -verify -CAfile ca-crt.pem -inform der -signer server-crt.pem -in sample.cms-der -nointern
Verification failure
14712:error:2E09D08A:CMS routines:CMS_verify:signer certificate not found:.\crypto\cms\cms_smime.c:333:
```

Of course, in this scenario I can still verify the signature because the certificate is included – but if I generate the signed file using the `-nocerts` option I end up in the failure scenario, regardless of whether I verify using `-nointern` or not.

**Step 3 Beta: SMIME instead of CMS**

I also tried using smime instead of cms, and interestingly, although the error message is the same, the error has a different error number, and it comes from a different part in the source code:

```
$ openssl smime -verify -CAfile ca-crt.pem -inform der -signer server-crt.pem -in sample.cms-der -nointern
Verification failure
13580:error:2107C080:PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_get0_signers:signer certificate not found:.\crypto\pkcs7\pk7_smime.c:466:
```

The version of openssl I'm using is `OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue I'm investigating is part of a larger context, and it turns out the problem I encountered in this specific test case is rather silly: I was using the wrong parameter to indicate the signing cert. One shouldn't use `-signer` to indicate the signing certificate when verifying, but `-certfile`:

```
$ openssl cms -verify -CAfile ca-crt.pem -inform der -certfile server-crt.pem -in sample.cms-der -nointern
Verification successful
```

And it works with SMIME as well:

```
$ openssl smime -verify -CAfile ca-crt.pem -inform der -certfile server-crt.pem -in sample.cms-der -nointern
Verification successful
```

I would typically delete the question altogether, but maybe somebody will find this useful in the future.